# undo cherry-pick in master branch

Tags: git, github

I am on master branch, I use cherry-pick merged one commit from another branch:

On master branch, I cherry-pick the commit by:

```
git cherry-pick -x e89d1
```

There was no conflicts after cherry-pick. There was no other commits in master branch after this cherry-pick.

Now, I want to **undo** that cherry-pick, what is the correct way to abort this cherry-pick?

My git version is 2.6.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reset your branch to previous commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

Cherry-picked commit will remain there but it won't be visible because no branch or tag will point to it.

Eventually it will be removed by git garbage collector.